# geting value by comparing a date with a range of date scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

i am just new for this

i have 3 dataframes. The bis is just is just the test table by adding the approperiate sale_price using the synch_date , and comparing it with DEBUT And FIn

Here is what i did , am just new to scala, and spark here what i did , is any one who can help hpw to make this join request , thank you .

```
 val histocaisse = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("C:\\Users\\MHT\\Desktop\\histocaisse.csv")
    .withColumn("pos_id",'pos_id.cast(LongType))
    .withColumn("DEBUT",'DEBUT.cast(DateType))
    .withColumn("FIN",'FIN.cast(DateType))
    .withColumn("PRIXV",'PRIXV.cast(DoubleType))



  val test = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("C:\\Users\\MHT\\Desktop\\test.csv")

  test.show


  val bis = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("C:\\Users\\MHT\\Desktop\\bis.csv")
    .select("pos_id","synch_date","sale_price")



 +------+----------+----------+----------+
|pos_id|start_date|  end_date|sale_price|
+------+----------+----------+----------+
|     1|2000-01-02|2000-01-07|       2.5|
|     2|2000-02-18|2000-02-25|       2.3|
|     3|2000-03-02|2000-03-25|      14.0|
+------+----------+----------+----------+

+------+----------+
|pos_id|synch_date|
+------+----------+
|     1|2000-01-03|
|     2|2000-02-19|
|     3|2000-03-20|
+------+----------+

+------+----------+----------+
|pos_id|synch_date|sale_price|
+------+----------+----------+
|     1|2000-01-03|       2.5|
|     2|2000-02-19|       2.3|
|     3|2000-03-20|        14|
+------+----------+----------+
```

The idea is to join the first and the second based on the pos_id , and we will test in which range of date is the synch_date , in order to match the sale_price with appropriate interval between start_date and end_date .
For example for the date 2000-01-03 we see in which range is it and then we take the appropriate sale_price from the first dataframe 
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: please clarify your question a little bit more. do you want to join the first and second dataframe to get the third one? if yes what is the logic? and if no what is it you want exactly? your sale_price matches with PRIXV. is it coincidence or fact? what about pos_id? ..... and many more

Comment: @RameshMaharjan hello thanks you are always saving me , i edited the question is it better ?

Comment: what would you do if the synch_date is not within range of start_date and end_date? and what if there are multiple date ranges that matches with synch_date?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan thanks for answering.Well , it won't be possible to not having any matching with the ranges .thanks ,

Comment: is the answer helpful then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `dataframes` as

```
df1
+------+----------+----------+----------+
|pos_id|start_date|  end_date|sale_price|
+------+----------+----------+----------+
|     1|2000-01-02|2000-01-07|       2.5|
|     2|2000-02-18|2000-02-25|       2.3|
|     3|2000-03-02|2000-03-25|      14.0|
+------+----------+----------+----------+

df2
+------+----------+
|pos_id|synch_date|
+------+----------+
|     1|2000-01-03|
|     2|2000-02-19|
|     3|2000-03-20|
+------+----------+
```

I would suggest you **not to** `join` with `pos_id` but rather I suggest you to `join` using condition match as below

```
df2.join(df1, (df2("synch_date") >= df1("start_date") && (df2("synch_date") <= df1("end_date"))), "left")
        .select(df2("pos_id"), $"synch_date", $"sale_price")
```

you should have final `dataframe` as

```
+------+----------+----------+
|pos_id|synch_date|sale_price|
+------+----------+----------+
|1     |2000-01-03|2.5       |
|2     |2000-02-19|2.3       |
|3     |2000-03-20|14.0      |
+------+----------+----------+
```

choice between `left-join` or `inner-join` or `outer-join` is how you want your `dataframe`. And you can include `pos_id` too in the `join` process.

If you want to add `pos_id` in the `join` then you can something like below

```
df2.join(df1, (df1("pos_id") === df2("pos_id")) && (df2("synch_date") >= df1("start_date")) && (df2("synch_date") <= df1("end_date")), "left")
    .select(df2("pos_id"), $"synch_date", $"sale_price")
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: how can include the pos_id , becuase , it is  like a key , for joining .How can i integrate it , Thanks a lot :)

Comment: i can do the same thing with other column if i want ?

Comment: certainly @MaherHTB :)